# SQL Query To Get Structured Result

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Sir, below is my SQL query, followed with two images of **Query Result** & **Required Output**.

As you can see on **Result image** that I have got this output from executing the following query.

There is second image of **Required Output**. I would need to display the output in that format. As First Department name should be at top & below Project details correspond to that department. The same cycle should get repeated for each and every department.

How should I achieve this ?

**SQL Code:**

```
DECLARE @ColName varchar(20)=null,
        @Query varchar(MAX)=null,
        @DepartmentName varchar(50)=null,
        @deptt_code varchar(4)=null,
        @DistrictId varchar(4)='0001',
        @Deptt_Id char(4)=null,
        @stYear varchar(4)=null, 
        @cYear varchar(4)=null,
        @yr varchar(9)='2017-2018',
        @tno int

BEGIN

set @stYear = SUBSTRING(@yr,0,5);
set @cYear = SUBSTRING(@yr,6,4);

--CREATE DYNAMIC TABLE WITH COLs
DECLARE @DepartmentTable table
(
  department_name varchar(50),
  department_code varchar(4)
 );
DECLARE @ProjectTable table
(
  project_name varchar(130),
  project_code varchar(15),
  department_code varchar(4),
  department_name varchar(50),
  district_code varchar(4),
  district_name varchar(30),
  tehsil_code varchar(6),
  tehsil_name varchar(30),
  service_code varchar(3),
  [service_name] varchar(30),
  sector_code varchar(3),
  sector_name varchar(30),
  project_start_year varchar(8),
  project_compl_year varchar(8),
  financial_year varchar(9)
);

--Insert into Department Table
INSERT INTO @DepartmentTable (department_code, department_name)
select deptt_code,deptt_name+'('+ RTRIM(LTRIM(deptt_short))+')' as dept_name from m_Department 
  where deptt_code in (select distinct department_code from t_Project_Details where district_id=@DistrictId
  and financial_year=@yr);


--Insert into Project Table With Corresponding Department Name & Code
  insert into @ProjectTable (
                                    department_code,
                                    project_code,
                                    project_name,
                                    department_name,
                                    district_code,
                                    district_name,
                                    tehsil_code,
                                    tehsil_name,
                                    service_code,
                                    [service_name],
                                    sector_code,
                                    sector_name,
                                    project_start_year,
                                    project_compl_year,
                                    financial_year
                                   )
        SELECT pd.department_code,
               pd.project_Code,
               pd.project_name,
               d.deptt_name,
               pd.district_id,
               di.district_name,
               pd.tehsil_id,
               t.tehsil_name,
               pd.service_code,
               s.[service_name],
               pd.sector_code,
               se.sector_name,
               CONVERT(varchar,YEAR(pd.project_initiation_fin_from_yr)) + ' ' + CONVERT(varchar(3),pd.project_initiation_fin_from_yr,100) as project_start_year,
               CONVERT(varchar,YEAR(pd.project_initiation_fin_to_yr)) + ' ' + CONVERT(varchar(3),pd.project_initiation_fin_to_yr,100) as project_compl_year,
               pd.financial_year

        FROM t_Project_Details pd

        INNER JOIN m_Department d
        ON d.deptt_code=pd.department_code

        INNER JOIN m_Service s
        ON s.service_code = pd.service_code 

        INNER JOIN m_Sector se
        ON se.sector_code=pd.sector_code 

        INNER JOIN m_District di
        ON di.district_code=pd.district_id

        INNER JOIN m_Tehsil t
        ON t.tehsil_code = pd.tehsil_id

        WHERE 
               district_id=@DistrictId and 
               financial_year=@yr;

--select all from Department Table;
select * from @ProjectTable;
END
```

**Query Result Image:** https://drive.google.com/open?id=0Bxn7UXgmstmRaS1qX21kbjlwZzg

**Required Output Image:** https://drive.google.com/open?id=0Bxn7UXgmstmRekJkUWhBcmNCbk0

Comment: Don't include images in place of actual text code.  Also, your question is very long, and it is _your_ job to tell us where the actual problem is.

Comment: Sir, Images I have include to just show you what I got and what i required.

Comment: Problem is to I am unable to get my output in specified format as I have provided in Output Image. Is it achievable ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your required output is a presentation layer issue; SQL can return your results but cannot make one row contain one thing and following rows contain many different things in a different format.

A SQL resultset will contain the same number of columns in all rows each with the same datatype.

Use something like SSRS to acheive your desire output.